# Finding and reading from a file path

Tags: python

in my game I'm using text files to save data, the code looks like this:

```
 file = open('username.txt','r')
 username = file.read()
 file.close()
```

The only problem I have is that I want it to get that file from a subfolder called PlayerData, this complicates things as you need to find where the file is being ran from so I use this code:

```
absolutepath = os.path.abspath(__file__) # finds the location of the running file
```

when I print the absolutepath, I get the result

> O:\Jackpot Studios\PyMemer BETA\pymemer.py

this is so when anyone plays the game, it will find the path and not have to be fixed to a certain location - but I want the file path to look like this

> Drive:\Folder\PyMemer BETA\playerdata

so how do I remove the 'pymemer.py' and add the '\playerdata', then read 'username.txt' from the filepath

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

absolutepath = os.path.abspath(__file__)

filename = os.path.basename(absolutepath)
print(absolutepath)

dirname = absolutepath.replace(filename, "playerdata")

filename = dirname + "\\username.txt" 

file = open(filename, 'r')
username = file.read()
file.close()
```

You can add what you want to do after reading the file then.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer your question. Could you specify the structure of your project?

I guess "Drive:\Folder\PyMemer BETA" is the root directory of your project?

In this case, you can store the root directory "Drive:\Folder\PyMemer BETA" in an environment variable named root_path when starting your project.

This is how to create the environment variable at the start of your project:

```
import os
os.environ["root_path"] = "Drive:\Folder\PyMemer BETA\"
```

And then you can access this environment variable in your code in this way:

```
import os
root_path = os.environ['root_path'] # root_path contains Drive:\Folder\PyMemer BETA\
```

Then, you can access username.txt with that path:

```
path_file = root_path + '/' + 'playerdata/username.txt'
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is generic. You can reuse it for all the files in your project. And it will continue to work even if your root project path changes as long as you update the root_path environment variable

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
import os
absolutepath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
# absolutepath is now "/Jackpot Studios/PyMemer BETA/pymemer.py"
parent_path = os.path.dirname(absolutepath)
# parent_path is now '/Jackpot Studios/PyMemer BETA'
target_path = os.path.join(parent_path, "playerdata")
# target_path is now '/Jackpot Studios/PyMemer BETA/playerdata'
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers might me correct but it will not run fine if the file has been saved with another name.
What you can do is

First import Path

```
#import path
from pathlib import Path
```

Then replace this line

```
absolutepath = os.path.abspath(__file__) # finds the location of the running file
```

With this line

```
absolutepath = os.getcwd()
```

Or with this line

```
absolutepath = Path.resolve()
```